# HTML document + js + images size in kb

Tags: html, size, sizeof

I want to be able to find out how long a page will take to download. I can calculate how long it will take when I know the size of the page including html page, javascript and images (including background images).

Is there a way to calculate this easily? Or an online resource perhaps?

Currently I use FF's Web Developer toolbar that shows the document size, but not with background images...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try Firebug.
Theres a tab named "network".
All loaded files are shown there with size.